# Examples of triality in mathematics

Tags: examples

There are tons of interesting examples of duality in mathematics (Poincaré  duality, Verdier duality, Stone duality, s-duality, Tannaka duality, Koszul duality, Spanier-Whitehead duality ... ). What examples are there of triality in mathematics?

Note: this is not a duplicate of the question about trichotomies in mathematics. A trichotomy is any sort of classification into three. A triality is a classification into three where the relationship between those three is some sort of equivalence relation (especially one emphasizing that though things *appear* opposite they are in some sense the same).

Comment: I think triality more often than not refers to operations involving the exceptional degree-$3$ outer automorphism of $Spin(8)$.

Comment: There are a number of references here, not all of them are solely on Spin(8) https://mathoverflow.net/q/116666/4177

Comment: John Baez's article The Octonions makes the case for a close relationship between triality, octonions, and the exceptional Lie algebras: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0105155.pdf. By "triality" he means a nondegenerate trilinear map, see section 2.4.

Comment: Not a duplicate. A trichotomy is any sort of classification into three, a triality is a classification into three where the relationship between those three is some sort of equivalence relation (more specifically, some sort of equivalence relation emphasizing how things which *appear* opposite are actually the same).

Comment: @Trent You may wish to edit some elaboration of that comment into your question. Perhaps you can give a more precise definition of "triality", or list some specific features of the dualities you'd like to see generalized.

Comment: Not that I know anything at all even close to this, but Koszul duality has been called a triality: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2621

Comment: I like the question, but I agree with @j.c.:  I think it takes some considerable work (at least for me) even to understand what it is, aside from the presence of 3 arms in the Dynkin diagram, that makes triality deserve the name 'triality'; so I'm not sure that I'd recognise another example of the same phenomenon when I saw one, even with the clarification in your comment above (since edited into the question).

Answer (score 8):

There are uses of ternary structures in the sense of $Z_3$-graded structures as generalizations of super-geometry (or $Z_2$-graded structures) in theoretical physics.

See papers by Richard Kerner:

Ternary and non-associative structures, “International Journal of Geometric Methods in Physics”, (volume en l’honneur de M. Dubois-Violette), Vol. 5,No. 8, pp. 1265-1294 (2008)

A Z3-generalization of Pauli’s principle, quark algebra and Lorentz invariance, AIP Conference Proceedings (International School of Field Theory and Gravitation, Petropolis 2011, Brésil), 1483, pp. 144-168 (2012)

and others on his [homepage](http://www.lptl.jussieu.fr/users/kerner).

There is also the use of non-degenerate 3-forms as a generalization of symplectic manifolds, see

- Ševera, Pavol; Weinstein, Alan Poisson geometry with a 3-form background. Noncommutative geometry and string theory (Yokohama, 2001). Progr. Theoret. Phys. Suppl. No. 144 (2001), 145–154.

Answer (score 5):

An interesting duality is polarity with respect to a conic in the projective plan. A conic is determined by a bilinear form $q$ (the equation of the conic being $q(u,u)=0$) and one way to describe the polarity is to say that the polar of a point corresponding to a vector $v$ in the underlying $3$-space is the line whose equation is $q(v,\cdot)=0$.

Now, this yields an immediate equivalent for trialities: consider a cubic, it is determined by a trilinear form $t(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ and two points (with corresponding vectors $u$, $v$) and a line are in triality if $t(u,v,\cdot)=0$ is an equation of the line.

Comment: Being a relationship between “two points and a line”, this one rather seems to lose the symmetry of the original duality, so feels less compelling to me as a candidate for “triality”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Well, in duality you usually have two objects of different nature, so this seems difficult to avoid. You can see the line as a point in the dual space if you prefer (so, given a cubic, every two point define a polar point in the dual space) or use a conic to be able to identify lines with points.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Can't we generalize to this higher 'ality'?

Comment: @VS. yes, you can simply use higher-degree homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Perhaps you may want to give a general answer.